# How to pass string arguments with spaces to SQL notebook in databricks?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a SQL notebook(notebookA) where I want to pass arguments from another notebook(notebookB).

```
---notebookA---
SELECT $v as $c
```

When I do this from notebook B, it is giving me result.

```
---notebookB---
%run ./notebookA $v='james' $c=name
```

[image]

But when there is a space in value it is giving me error like below

```
---notebookB---
%run ./notebookA $v='james potter' $c=name

Failed to parse %run command: string matching regex `\$[\w_]+' expected but `p' found)
```

What would be the solution then?

Answer (score 1):

Magic commands do not allow variables to be passed. Instead you can use dbutils.

Python:

```
dbutils.notebook.run("notebookA", 60, {"v": "james potter", "c": name})
```

Reference: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html

Comment: magic commands **do** allow variable to pass. You can see that from my first example. I am getting error when there is a space in value. Also I think `"c":name}` will give me an error.